# Missing argument 1 for page::sponsor()

Tags: php, oop, silverstripe

i'm having this really frustrating error. I'm calling the sponsor function from another function and pass an argument. The sponsor function however keeps giving the missing argument error.

here's my code:

```
// get random sale
public function RandomSale() {
    static $sale = null;
    if(!isset($sale)){
        $sale = Sale::get()->filter(array('Title:not' => null))->sort("RAND()")->Limit('1');
        $this->sponsor(8);
    }
    return $sale;
}

public function sponsor($memberid) {
    $sponsor = Sponsor::get()->filter(array('MemberID' => $memberid))->Limit('1');
    return $sponsor;
}
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: Are you sure this is the only place you call `sponsor()` function?

Comment: yes, this is the only place.

Comment: can you paste the whole error message, maybe with trace? Try to go to dev mode, then you'll see a tracelog and also from where sponsor method is called...

Comment: [WARNING] MISSING ARGUMENT 1 FOR PAGE::SPONSOR(), CALLED IN FRAMEWORK/VIEW/VIEWABLEDATA.PHP ON LINE 363 AND DEFINED

Comment: If you remove the line `$this->sponsor(8);` from your `RandomSale` function, does the error go away?

Answer (score 3):

Try naming your `sponsor()` function to something more specific, like `SponsorByID($memberID)`. You may have a naming conflict between your Sponsor DataObject and your `sponsor()` function.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that the number 8 is even being passed to the method sponsor(). Try entering it as `$this->sponsor('8')` to see if you still get the error. If not, then happy days.

P.S. As elliot_at_silverstripe says, try to clear up your code to follow the SilverStripe coding conventions too.. you may thank yourself later. :) 
https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/getting_started/coding_conventions/